# Show the set of GCD's of two elements in an integral domain is the set of associates of their GCD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Sorry if this seem trivial, but im slightly stuck:

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of an integral domain "$R$" and let $d$ be the $\gcd(a,b)$. Show that the set of GCD's of $a$ and $b$ is the set of associates of $d$.

If $a$ and $b$ are associates, show each is a GCD of $a$ and $b$.

Well: 
If $GCD(a,b)=d$ then $a=dx$ and $b=dy$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{Z^+}$

I know $a$ and $b$ are associate if $a|b$ and $b|a$.

Also if $a$ and $b$ are associate $a=bc$ and $b=ga$ where $g$ and $c$ are units in $R$.

Im just not sure how to fit this all together. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How do you define $GCD(a,b)$ ?

Comment: Greatest common divisor

Comment: What is greatest in a ring like $R[x]$?

Comment: If you have two elements is an integral domain, then they will both have a greatest common divisor, d

Comment: You typically need to define it like this: $d=gcd(a,b)$ if and only if $d \mid a$ and $d\mid b$ and if $d' \in D$ is another element such that $d' \mid a$ and $d' \mid b$, then $d' \mid d$.

Comment: Your above statement is highly untrue.  Not every domain is a gcd domain.

Comment: ok, well I guess I eluded to that when I said $a=dx$ and $b=dy$

Comment: Sorry, I should say that IF they have a gcd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30614/discussion-between-cpm-and-the-physics-student).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of GCD(a,b) is as follows.  If $d$ is a $\gcd(a,b)$, then $d \mid a$ and $d\mid b$ and for any $d'\in D$ with $d'\mid a$ and $d' \mid b$, $d' \mid d$.

Let $d_1$ and $d_2$ be $\gcd(a,b)$.  We prove they are associates.  Certainly $d_1$ and $d_2$ both divide $a$ and $b$. Since $d_1$ is a $\gcd(a,b)$, $d_1 \mid d_2$.  Similarly, $d_2 \mid d_1$.  Thus they are associates.  If $d_1$ is an associate of $d=\gcd(a,b)$, then $d_1=\lambda d$ for a unit $\lambda$.  Thus $d$ is a divisor of $a$ and $b$, so $dk=a$ and $dl=b$.  But then $d_1 \lambda^{-1}k=a$ and $d_1 \lambda^{-1}l=b$, so $d_1$ is a common divisor.

Moreover, if $d'$ is another element which divides both $a$ and $b$, we know that $d' \mid d$ since $d$ is a $\gcd(a,b)$.  But then $d'm=d$ for some $m$. Then $d'm=\lambda^{-1}d_1$ which implies $d'(m\lambda)=d_1$, so $d' \mid d_1$ and this proves $d_1$ is a $\gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: Thanks CPM! This is clear!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  gcd in the integers can be a good guide often, but can lead you astray.  You realize pretty quickly how nice the integers really are as a ring.  We are quite spoiled.