# Content of a polynomial is unique

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the content of a polynomial in a integral domain unique upto units?
Here content is defined as a non unit element dividing all the terms of polynomial and after the division the polynomial doesn't have any more non unit divisor for every terms in the divided polynomial.

Comment: As you write the definition, $X+1$ has no defined content?

Answer (score 0):

No, not as "a non unit element". The content is the greatest common divisor of the coefficients in a gcd domain. It is unique up to units, as the gcd is unique up to units, see this duplicate:

[Show the set of GCD's of two elements in an integral domain is the set of associates of their GCD](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493258/show-the-set-of-gcds-of-two-elements-in-an-integral-domain-is-the-set-of-associ)

Comment: A priori, there is no gcd in an general integral domain - but in that case, the content is not defined

Comment: What if we take content as a set? Are they all unique to unit?

Comment: Yes, it is, see the duplicate.

Comment: What if I don't take gcd domain?

Comment: In many algebra books the content is defined only for factorial rings. Then it is defined. In general, it is not defined, see also Hagen's remark.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Actually polynomial content *is* defined in any commutative ring as the ideal generated by the coefficients, and a generalization of Gauss's content Lemma holds, viz. the Dedekind Mertens Lemma:  $\ c(f)^n c(fg) = c(f)^n c(f)c(g),\ \ n = {\rm deg}(g)\ \ $